# Adding sub-directory and suffix to retrieved image path

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, field

I'm currently using the command:

```
<php echo get('external_photo'); ?>
```

to retrieve a full path to an image from a custom field, lets say:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/images/test.jpg
```

and I was looking to change the path of the image retrived to something like:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/images/thumbs/test_thumb.jpg
```

Can anyone tell what would be the best way to append the sub-directory and the suffix to the path of the image?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$photoname = dirname(get('external_photo'))."/thumbs/".basename(get('external_photo'));
$photothumb = str_replace(".jpg", "_thumb.jpg", $photoname);
echo $photothumb;
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the php dirname() function
ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

and then just use the '.' character to append strings in php

```
<?php echo dirname(get('external_photo'))."/thunbs/test_thumb.jpg" ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! That works great to append the sub-directory but I would still need to get only the "filename.jpg" part from the 'external_photo' output. Here you're just giving it a new name: test_thumb.jpg

Comment: $photo = "uploads/Bla.jpg";
$photothumb = str_replace(".jpg", "_thumb.jpg", $photo);
echo $photothumb;
seems to work for that part but I'm not sure how to combine the two.

Comment: This seems to work: echo dirname('http://www.mywebsite.com/uploads/test.jpg')."/thumbs/";
echo basename('http://www.mywebsite.com/uploads/test.jpg');

Comment: $photoname = dirname('http://www.mysite.com/uploads/test.jpg')."/thumbs/".basename('http://www.mysite.com/uploads/test.jpg');
$photothumb = str_replace(".jpg", "_thumb.jpg", $photoname);
echo $photothumb;

Comment: Sorry, did u figure it out?

Comment: Yes, I think so but your help was crucial, thank you very much!